# Updating all attribute data in Feature Layer using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, cursor

I have a layer with over 250,000+ features, and I want to update all the attribute data using ArcObjects and C#. I have written the code below and it takes around 3 hours to perform the update. Can you suggest whether the code below is efficient enough and any suggestion regarding the delta tables please?

```
public void updateWithCursor(IWorkspace workspace, IFeatureClass featureClass, List<Update> updateList)
    {
        using (ComReleaser comReleaser = new ComReleaser())
        {
            IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)workspace;

            // Start an edit session
            workspaceEdit.StartEditing(false);

            // Start an edit operation
            workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();
            // Use IFeatureClass.Search to create a search cursor.
            IFeatureCursor searchCursor = featureClass.Search(null, false);
            comReleaser.ManageLifetime(searchCursor);

            // Find the positions of the fields used to get and set values.
            int idIndex = featureClass.FindField("ID");
            int serialIndex = featureClass.FindField("SERIAL");
            int cityIndex = featureClass.FindField("CITY");
            int updateDateIndex = featureClass.FindField("UPDATEDATE");

            int counter = 0;
            IFeature feature = null;
            while ((feature = searchCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
            {
                string searchValue = feature.get_Value(idIndex).ToString();

                if (searchValue != "")
                {
                    Update upd = updateList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == searchValue);

                    if (upd != null)
                    {                            
                        feature.set_Value(serialIndex , upd.serialNo);
                        feature.set_Value(cityIndex , upd.city);
                        feature.set_Value(updateDateIndex, DateTime.Now);
                        feature.Store();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(counter++);
                }
            }

            workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();

            // Stop the edit session
            workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use a Dictionary instead of a List for your updates, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The process you are doing should not take that long, and the bottleneck is your `UpdateList`.  On each iteration of of your search cursor, the `UpdateList` is searched from the beginning until a matching `ID` is found.  It would be much more efficient to use a [HashTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) so you can create a lookup via the `ID` to update your table.  From [this page](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/dictionary.htm):

> Both lists and dictionaries are used to store collections of data. The
>   Dictionary is based on a hash table, that means it uses a hash lookup,
>   which is a rather efficient algorithm to look up things, on the other
>   hand, a list you have to go element by element until it finds the
>   result from beginning to the result each time.

So what you can do is set up your `UpdateList` as a Dictionary where your values are a Dictionary where every entry would be:

`UpdateDict[id] = valueDict   //where valueDict is {"city": "Chicago", "serialNo": 100}`

My C# is pretty rusty, but maybe in your search cursor you can do something like this:

```
while ((feature = searchCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
    {
        string searchValue = feature.get_Value(idIndex).ToString();

        if ((searchValue != "") && (UpdateDict.ContainsKey(searchValue)))
        {
            Dictionary upd = UpdateDict[searchValue];  //use this update dict instead of list

            if (upd != null)
            {                            
                feature.set_Value(serialIndex , upd["serialNo"]);
                feature.set_Value(cityIndex , upd["city"]);
                feature.set_Value(updateDateIndex, DateTime.Now);
                feature.Store();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(counter++);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch the search cursor and do something like this:

```
foreach(var upd in updateList)
{
    IFeature feature = featureClass.GetFeature(upd.id); 
    feature.set_Value(serialIndex , upd.serialNo);
    feature.set_Value(cityIndex , upd.city);
    feature.set_Value(updateDateIndex, DateTime.Now);
    feature.Store();
}
```

Now you don't have to search through updateList or put it in a hashtable.

Also, if this is a standalone program (not an Add-in) then you'll want to wrap all your ArcObjects code to run in not only the same thread, but a SingleThreadedApartment thread.

So something like this would do:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread((x) =>
                { //ArcObjects code
                });
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
            t.Join();
        }
```

The reason is that all ArcObjects are SingleThreadedApartment [STA] COM objects. When using an STA COM object created on a different thread there is a significant delay when marshaling calls between threads. STA objects created in a MultiThreadedApartment [MTA] (which is the default for Console apps, WPF, Forms, etc.) will actually be created on a separate STA thread. This means any interaction with ArcObjects will incur the performance penalty for marshaling calls between threads. By creating an STA thread that penalty is removed.